# Elements in a Jlist are not displaying can someone help me?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

So I basically copied the code from the oracle documentation but nothing will display. There are no problems with the files I already checked that. Here's the code:

```
v=Archivio.LetturaRic();       
dlm=new DefaultListModel();
for(int i=0; i<v.size();i++)
{
   dlm.addElement(((Ricetta)v.get(i)).nome); 
}
list=new JList(dlm);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setSelectedIndex(0);
list.addListSelectionListener(this);
list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
```

Comment: are you adding the list to any container?

Comment: Does "v" contain any Objects? Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) when you ask a question so we have code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `list=new JList(dlm);` A better way to approach this is to instead create the list at start-up and at that point call `list.setModel(dlm);`.  But as @camickr said, post an SSCCE so we don't need to make assumptions or ask 101 questions about the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);